# YOLOv5 - Convert to tflite but make scores type float32 instead of int32

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolov5, tflite

I am trying to use a custom object detection model trained with YOLOv5 converted to tflite for an Android app (using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) exact TensorFlow example).

The model has been converted to tflite by using the YOLOv5 converter like this:
`python export.py --weights newmodel.pt --include tflite --int8 --agnostic-nms`
This is the export.py function that exports model as tflite:
`def export_tflite(keras_model, im, file, int8, data, nms, agnostic_nms, prefix=colorstr('TensorFlow Lite:')):
# YOLOv5 TensorFlow Lite export
import tensorflow as tf

```
LOGGER.info(f'\n{prefix} starting export with tensorflow {tf.__version__}...')
batch_size, ch, *imgsz = list(im.shape)  # BCHW
f = str(file).replace('.pt', '-fp16.tflite')

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
if int8:
    from models.tf import representative_dataset_gen
    dataset = LoadImages(check_dataset(check_yaml(data))['train'], img_size=imgsz, auto=False)
    converter.representative_dataset = lambda: representative_dataset_gen(dataset, ncalib=100)
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.target_spec.supported_types = []
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
    converter.experimental_new_quantizer = True
    f = str(file).replace('.pt', '-int8.tflite')
if nms or agnostic_nms:
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops.append(tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS)

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(f, "wb").write(tflite_model)
return f, None`
```

The working example uses these tensors: [Working example model's tensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBxar.png)

My tensors look like this: [My custom model's tensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9mJ6.png)

The problem is that I don't know how to convert my output tensor's **SCORE** type from `int32` to `float32`. Therefore, the app does not work with my custom model (I think this is the only problem that is stopping my custom model from working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YoloV5 model is returning data in INT32 format. But **TensorBuffer does not support data type: INT32**.
To use On Device ML in Android, **use SSD models**. Because only SSD models are currently supported by tflite library.